# How to communicate with RS-422 device?

Tags: communication

I am trying to connect one Airmar EchoRange Plus Sonar sensor to my PC.

How should I go about it? (Since I am new to electronics I have this basic doubt, pardon me for that in advance).

The sensor utilizes RS-422 for communicating.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  The usual way to connect RS-422 devices to a PC is with a "USB RS-422 adaptor", of which there are very many models.  A lot depends on the details of what you are connecting and the software you want to receive the data.  Do you have the manual for your specific device?

Answer (score 1):

**SAFETY WARNING: IF THIS IS SAFETY EQUIPMENT FOR A BOAT, GET A PROFESSIONAL TO DO IT**

The usual way to connect RS-422 devices to a PC is with a "USB RS-422 adaptor", of which there are very many models. A lot depends on the details of what you are connecting and the software you want to receive the data. Do you have the manual for your specific device?

Try looking at [Airmar Cross Reference](https://www.airmar.com/xref)

To repeat: a lot depends on things like the distance of the cable, the type of the cable and so on.  How you run the adaptor depends on the software and operating system.

**THE FOLLOWING IS FOR GENERAL INFORMATION: YOU MUST USE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR YOUR PARTICULAR DEVICES**

You find a suitable RS-422 adaptor which suits your operating system, your budget and your mounting and connector requirements.  A typical kind plugs into USB and has five screw terminals.  You connect

| Adaptor | Airmar |
| --- | --- |
| TX+ | NMEA+ IN |
| TX- | NMEA- IN |
| RX+ | NMEA+ OUT |
| RX- | NMEA- OUT |
| GND | GND |

Airmar show this for one of their devices:
[image]
From Airmar

You find the wiring diagram for your Airmar device, which will show which colour wires for which signals.  (I blocked out the colour names because you **must** use the documentation for your particular device)
[image]
From Airmar